# Error converting PDF from Html using iText7 and C# .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, itext, maui, itext7

My code is large but I will make this easy to understand what I am trying to achieve. I am just trying to convert a PDF from a HTML string in C# using the library iText7 or ItextSharp Core and then it should open in a temporal or cache directory in Android.

This example I found on the internet worked for me:

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    // Add some text to the PDF
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello, world!"));

    // Close the document
    document.Close();

    // Create a copy of the MemoryStream
    MemoryStream copyStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());

    // Save the PDF to the Downloads folder
    string fileName = "myPDF.pdf";
    var downloadsPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "Downloads");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadsPath);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(downloadsPath, fileName);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await copyStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    // Launch the file using the FileLauncher
    await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
    {
        File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath)
    });
```

But this is not what I am looking for, I want to generate stuff in PDF from a HTML so I have tried this so far:

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    // Add some HTML content to the PDF
    string html = "<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
    using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
    {
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlStream, pdfDoc);
    }
    // Close the document
    document.Close();

    // Create a copy of the MemoryStream
    MemoryStream copyStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());

    // Save the PDF to the Downloads folder
    string fileName = "myPDF.pdf";
    var downloadsPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "Downloads");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadsPath);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(downloadsPath, fileName);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await copyStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    // Launch the file using the FileLauncher
    await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
    {
        File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath)
    });
```

the program runs ok but when hit the following line: `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlStream, pdfDoc);`

gives me this error:

> System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'

How do I make this work? Maybe I am lost in my code and might be wrong at converting to PDF from a html string. I made this simple because I am going to get a large html file from other server and set into a variable later.

Comment: What does the stack trace show?

Comment: Should I click "Show Call Stack"? if yes I can update the code showing it

Comment: You need to look at the stack trace to figure out where in the code the error originates.  How you get that is up to you.

Comment: Code runs ok but like I said when the breakpoint hits in the line where it says `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlStream, pdfDoc);` it gets the exception `ystem.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'` isn't this enough?

Comment: No, if it was enough I wouldn't suggest (twice) you look at the stack trace.  There are many overloads for `ConvertToPdf` and I'm not sure which one you are using.  The stack trace will hopefully show you where in the iText library the problem originates

Comment: i had the same issue : under linux BaseUri is null and throw exception. Try to set in the ConverterProperties : `props.SetBaseUrl(somepath)`